# How to crop .GIF to 4 parts

Tags: php, gif, crop

How to crop .GIF image to 4 parts i need ? I have 4 points - bottom x/y and top x/y and for every 4 parts.
Thank you for answers.

Comment: I'm not sure from your description exactly... do you want to divide a single image into four equal parts?

Comment: Well theoretically you only need 1 point to split the image to four. Just saying.

Comment: What have you done so far? Please show some code.

Answer (score 3):

The method [imagecopyresized](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) will help you. It is documented pretty well:

```
bool imagecopyresized ( resource $dst_image , resource $src_image , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $dst_w , int $dst_h , int $src_w , int $src_h )
```

> imagecopyresized() copies a
> rectangular portion of one image to
> another image. dst_image is the
> destination image, src_image is the
> source image identifier.
>
> In other words, imagecopyresized()
> will take an rectangular area from
> src_image of width src_w and height
> src_h at position (src_x,src_y) and
> place it in a rectangular area of
> dst_image of width dst_w and height
> dst_h at position (dst_x,dst_y).

You need to make sure that your gd library supports gifs though. But i think thats not anymore an issue.